# How to create Virtual URL in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url

I have routes like these,it means when i login in a account with `id=128`, my URL will be `http://127.0.0.1:1000/sv/128/account`.
I want to ask, How any ways create to another URL? `http://127.0.0.1:1000/sv/abczysslw/asswaeq` ,like this. it's better to encode. because i don't want them to see my `id`.

```
   Route::group(['prefix'=>'sv','middleware'=>'sinhvienLogin'],function(){
            Route::get('/student/home','StudentController@index')->name('student.dashboard');
            Route::get('/{id}/account','FrontendController@account')->name('sv.account');
        });
```

Comment: Use hashidis package.

Comment: You can use encode_decode like `bash_64`

Comment: https://jenssegers.com/64/easy-id-obfuscation-with-laravel-5 here you have an example

Comment: you are asking login. Why you use id here? After login all used data will be fetched from auth. Url must be protected.

Comment: @madankundu yup. it's better to recognize before. I wrote code a lot on that page.